# Graph API Facebook : user id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a business application which is using facebook and I need to send a private message to a connected user friend.

For getting all the user friends, I am using me/taggable_friends. In this way I have all the user friends but I can't retrieve the real friend user id. I need to know this field for sending a private message (or request or notification).

Regarding the FB documentation, this feature is only available for the "games" product but it's look like strange.
Maybe i'm doing something wrong but I don't understand how should I proceed.

Thank's for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

`taggable_friends` can (and should) only be used for tagging friends, you don´t even get an ID with it, only a tagging token (see Facebook docs).

For sending private messages, the best (and only) way is to use the Send Dialog of the JavaScript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

The user has to input the target friend and the message on his own, which is a requirement for the message anyway. It always has to be 100% user generated.

The Chat API is deprecated and should not be used anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm working on iOS and it seems working only with JS, isn't it ? Another question is, if i shouldn't use taggable_friends, how can I retrieve all the user friends with their pictures and names ? Thank's a lot.

Comment: you can only retrieve user friends if they use the app too, that´s part of the privacy update. you just will not get a full list, it is not possible anymore.

Comment: not sure how to send on ios, maybe this helps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ui-controls

Comment: on iOS you should use the Message Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#message-dialog

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, if you want to send a private message to another Facebook user, you should use the Message Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#message-dialog

This lets a user share a message with any of their FB friends, then return to your app. You can ensure the message contains a link which the recipients will be able to click on.